# Get Only Text values in <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html. 
Can someone help me in getting just the text value in `<li>`
I only want the text value from all `<span>` within `<li>` within that `<ul>`

Thanks for help.

Comment: have you debuged for `$.trim(document.getElementById("JobMemo " + jobId + "<li>")`

Comment: @Satpal there is a space in the ID... as a selector you need to escape it

Comment: Yes, but it gives value including all <li> and <span>. I just want text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$("[id='JobMemo " + jobId  + "']").text();
```

You should not use spaces, the reason is that, space character is not a valid for ID attribute.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

The [working draft for HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

You should also read [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: But every time i hit enter and write it comes on same line and not new line after refresh

Answer (score 1):

use `.text()`:

```
var id="JobMemo " + jobId + " <li>";
$.trim($("#"+id).text());
```

Comment: what about the space and `<li>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .text() like

```
var jobMemo = $.trim($("#JobMemo\\ " + jobId).text());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3YExL/)

Note: It is not a good idea to have space in the id....

Comment: @RS26 can you share a sample of generated html? looks like there is a space between `JobMemo` and the id

Comment: @RS26:the one which is there in ID of `<ul>`

Comment: Ok sir. But that is not giving me problem i guess. Still unable to get just the text:(

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the whole texts in an array you can do that

```
var jobId = '1';
var jobMemo = $("[id='JobMemo " + jobId  + "']")
.map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

You can see : http://jsfiddle.net/8QTru/1/

jobMemo is an array with only the text of each li. But, like Satpal sayd, your ID is not valid. I suggest you to replace your space (" ") by a underscore ("_") in order to get something like that : id="JobMemo_1" instead of id="JobMemo 1".

Comment: Trying it out,please give sometime